# prettier-tailwind-plugin isn't working as expected when I hit save in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, plugins, tailwind-css, prettier

I installed the prettier-plugin-tailwindcss and it successfully sorts the Tailwind classes when I run Prettier using `npx prettier --write index.html`. However, when I hit save in VScode,  the prettier-plugin-tailwindcss doesn't sort the Tailwind classes as expected.

I'm following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CntOc4hBcg&t=135s) and this [documentation](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/prettier-plugin-tailwindcss.git). As you can see I set the dev dependency correctly and have a `.prettierrc.json` in the project.``

[image: package.json]

[image: .prettierrc.json]

I was expecting that when I hit save it will automatically work as expected which is to sort tailwind classes but the plugin only works if run the prettier using `npx prettier --write index.html`

**Things I tried:**

I set the format on save to true and set the paths but it didn't resolve the problem.

[image: settings]

Answer (score 5):

Adding this line "plugins": ["prettier-plugin-tailwindcss"], to my .prettierrc.json file made the tailwind class sorting work for me. I'm using prettier 3.1.0 and prettier-plugin-tailwindcss 0.5.7

Comment: Note that you have to add the curly brace characters on both ends of the added line to keep the json format - example: {"plugins": ["prettier-plugin-tailwindcss"]}

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Settings > Text Editor > Formatting` and select "Format on Save".

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:
Also, I found out that if there's invalid html, prettier will spit errors and no formatting will happen. You can check for those errors in the terminal 'CTRL + SHIFT + U'. Probably more of a 'Prettier' thing rather than TailwindCSS thing.

---

I've had this issue for the past few days and I've managed to solve it after hours of wasted time and I still don't know what precisely fixed it, but here's what I did, hopefully it will help someone else out.

Just note, everything was working normally for me, then it stopped for no apparent reason, in the end I solved it by getting frustrated and I just brute forcing my way out, here's the finals steps I took:

1. I deleted *'the.prettierrc.json'* file altogether
2. Settings -> Search: 'prettier' -> Uncheck the *'Prettier:Require Config'* box.
3. I disabled pretty much any extension I wasn't using. I was trying to target formatting apps and decided on a big clean up.
4. I opened a file to test with -> CTRL + SHIFT + P
   -> *'Format Document With'*

This resulted in a prompt I hadn't had previously which asked me to choose my default formatter

-> Choose *'Prettier'.*

One of those things did it, now I'm back in business.

Comment: Why use a knife when you can also swing a wrecking ball en rebuild from there. Knowing what the system you're using does is more valuable than knowing where to copy a config from. Many good tips like check your output, do a manual format, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by adding `*.{jsx,html}` into `Prettier: Document Selectors` in the setting.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I also fixed this issue by adding Prettier as editor default formatter in visual studio settings

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).